# Variable will not Math.floor();

Tags: javascript, html, floor

I want a variable to update every second to the value of `Math.floor(jeans + jps)` with `jeans` being the number of jeans and `jps` being the number of jeans produced per second.

Here is a code snippet from my script:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    var prefloor = (jeans + jps);
    jeans = Math.floor(prefloor);
}, 1000);
```

However, this does not change the value of `jeans`. The following does change it, though:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    var prefloor = (jeans + jps);
    jeans = prefloor;
}, 1000);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the initial value of jeans and jps?

Comment: Jeans and jps are both 0, as defined by var jeans = 0; and var jps = 0;

Comment: do a `console.log(jeans,jps);` before the addition. they may not be numbers at all

Comment: This is hard to figure out without any debugging data or ways that jeans and jps change values. Can you do a fiddle reproducing your problem? It would really help anyone trying to fix it.

Comment: This would not make sense as the variables do increment without Math.floor(); If I did a !==nil check, they do exist.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9k3podrx/2/

Comment: Like I said, any comments here are simply just suggestions. Nobody knows the issue because you did not provide any debugging data, or information regarding how those values change. It would also be nice to show what they are at time of issue. What I mean is, the debug data for those values before it "doesn't do Math.Floor" and what the values were after the floor call.

Comment: Not seeing the issue your reporting on fiddle. Seems like JPS and jeans is always 0.

Comment: Looked at the fiddle, just to make sure: was the value of jps >= 1 when you were testing it?  If not, of course it wouldn't change; the delta value would be rounding down to 0, thus resulting in no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your delta value (jps) will be floored to 0 if it is <= 1.  Therefore, jeans will be changing by a value of 0, thus remaining constant.

Here's a JSFiddle where the value of Jeans changes when jsp >= 1:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9k3podrx/3/)

It works fine for this value, but decimal values will be rounded down, thus causing some inconsistencies.

### To Fix

To get the behavior you're probably looking for, what you're going to want to do is make a precise variable (not rounded), and then floor that value when displaying.

For instance:

```
var jeans=0;
var jps=0;

element.onclick=function(){jps+=0.2}

setInterval(function(){
  jeans+=jps;
  document.getElementById("jcount").innerHTML=Math.floor(jeans);  //use Math.floor only for display
},1000)
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9k3podrx/5/)

Comment: document.getElementById("jcount").innerHTML = Math.floor(jeans); works just fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your tailors variable is set to 0 in line 15. In line 19, you write

```
jps = (tailors*0.2);
```

which equals jps = (0 * 0.2) and the only way to get tailors++ is buy to buy something, which however requires at least 20, which will never happen. Set tailers = 1 and your counting will start.

*(It's not a valid answer yet, because the counting is not what it should look like ( not floored) but I can't write comments without having 50 Rep. sorry)*

Comment: Code works fine after dav's revision. Good guess though!

Comment: You get to twenty by clicking the image btw